# How to get the azure storage blob in fluter?

Tags: flutter, azure, dart, azure-blob-storage

I've connection string. I want to access the azure strorage container blobs. But the response is empty.

```
final _connectionString =
      'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey===;EndpointSuffix=';
var storage = AzureStorage.parse(_connectionString);
var file = await storage.getBlob("/text2imagemodels/lora/${loraVal.name}.jpeg");
azureImage = await file.stream.toBytes();
```

I want to display the image which I'm getting from the blob azure storage.